# Finding the region in sample data that fits to a known distribution

Tags: distributions, matlab, fitting, qq-plot

Given sample data that have a known probability distribution for large x and an unknown probability distribution for small x, what is the best way to find the value of x where the known probability distribution begins? I imagine trying a bunch of qq plots and then seeing where the best fits are would be how to go about this, but I'm wondering how to automate this / the best way of doing this, preferably in MATLAB. (I hope this makes sense. I'm not a mathematician / statistician.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There several possible approaches. One is to optimize a goodness-of-fit criterion like the Kolmogorov-Smirnov (max CDF difference) or the Cramer-van-Mieses (L1 differences between CDFs) statistics. As you are interested, however, in the region $x>x_0$, you can just use the complementary CDF $\overline{F}(x) = P(X>x)=1-F(x)$. Then the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistics, e.g., becomes
$$KS = \max_{x>x_0} | \overline{F}_{emp}(x) - \overline{F}_{fit}(x)|$$
where $\overline{F}_{emp}$ is the complementary CDF directly estimated from the data, and $\overline{F}_{fit}$ is the complementary CDF computed from the estimated distribution parameters.

Another approach, which could be combined with the above method, would be to demand that the probability density is continuous at the transition, i.e.
$$\hat{f}_{left}(x_0) = \hat{f}_{right}(x_0)$$
where $\hat{f}_{left}$ is estimated in a non-parametric way with a kernel-density estimator and $\hat{f}_{right}$ is estimated parametrically from your thereetical distribution.

For a use case, see sections 4.1 and 4.3 of the following study (the threshold is named $w_0$):

> Dalitz: ["Estimating Wealth Distribution: Top Tail and Inequality."](https://lionel.kr.hsnr.de/%7Edalitz/data/publications/fb03-tb-2016-01.pdf) Technical Report No. 2016-01, Hochschule Niederrhein, Fachbereich Elektrotechnik und Informatik, 2016

Comment: +1 Thank you. Could you please elaborate on the first paragraph? How would you recommend optimizing the goodness-of-fit criterion from the complementary CDF? My distribution for X > x (precise value to be determined, of course) is non-normally distributed, if that matters.

Comment: I have elaborated on this. For the anaolgous formula for the Cramer-van-Mieses statistics, see formula (18) in the cited reference.

Comment: Curious as to why you define complementary CDF and then define KS in terms of that, rather than just defining KS in terms of the more familiar CDF? $|\bar F_{emp}(x) - \bar F_{fit}(x)| = |F_{emp}(x)-F_{fit}(x)|$ for all $x$, right?

Comment: Thanks. @cdalitz I forgot to mention that x can only take on discrete values. Does that matter here?

Comment: Statistiscs based on the CDF are defined both for disrete and continuous random variables.

Comment: @cdalitz +1 Also, would I want the one- or two-sided KS test here? (I'm reading about this now to try to understand.)

Comment: What is the point of a statistiscal test? As far as I understood your question, you are looking for the optimal threshold value $x_0$, not about a binary yes/no answer.

Comment: @cdalitz Just to return to this to make sure I understand, I would want to do a goodness-of-fit test using something like (in the case of KS) the R function 'disc_ks_test()', modified to compute the complementary cdf, and find the largest value of x s.t. p < 0.05 for example?

Comment: (I'm not a mathematician or statistician, but I hope I got that reasonably correct.)

Comment: The p-value is not of interest. In Fig. 4 of the cited reference, the y-axis is the value of the test statistics and the x-axis is the threshold value $x_0$. You can compute KS directly with the formlua given in my anser: as your x is discrete, the maximum only goes over a discrete set of values.